# Angular - Separating variables for each show and hide element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create a custom toggle accordion menu. I want to show and hide individual elements one by one. I have stripped the function down to the nuts and bolts.

I have made attempts to separate variables for each element I want to show and hide. [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3w6emvc/)

This is my markup

```
<section ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="accordionCtrl">
   <div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
             <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleOne)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                              <span>Some text goes here!</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseOne" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleOne}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
<!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleTwo)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>Some text goes here!</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseTwo" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleTwo}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
<!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->

<div class="frq-accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <!-- PANEL STARTS HERE-->
            <div ng-click="frqToggle(hiddenToggleThree)" class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    <span>Some text goes here!</span>
                </div>
            </div><!-- PANEL HEADING ENDS HERE -->
            <div id="collapseThree" ng-class="{isHidden: hiddenToggleThree}" class="panel-collapse">
                <p>Hidden menu is open</p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- PANEL ENDS HERE -->
    </div>
<!-- FRQ ACCORDION CONTAINER ENDS HERE -->
```

ANGULAR

```
angular
  .module('myApp')
   .controller('futureCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){


$scope.hiddenToggleOne = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleTwo = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleThree = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleFour = false;
$scope.hiddenToggleFive = false;

$scope.frqToggle = function (toggleElem) {
    toggleElem = !toggleElem;
}

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller function `frqToggle` you are just setting the local variable `toggleElem`, and not modifying your scope variables.

You can dynamically set the scope variables:

```
$scope.frqToggle = function (toggleElem) {
  $scope[toggleElem] = !$scope[toggleElem];
}
```

You will then need to modify your `ng-click` to pass the name of the element rather than the element's value.

Comment: ng-click="frqToggle()" ?

Comment: `ng-click="frqToggle('hiddenToggleOne')"` should do the trick. Just need to change the param to a string since if you don't wrap it in single quotes angular will evaluate it and pass the value.

Comment: Where I have specified my variables $scope.hiddenToggleOne = false; etc  is there a better of doing it ? Just think about if i was create a loop for this block of code i don't want keep calling out my variable in the controller

Comment: If you are rendering these in a loop, then I would use an array on scope to track what is open/closed. You could then call your `frqToggle()` with the index of the item you want to turn on/off.